# total values does not change whereas sub-total changes

Tags: javascript

i have a js code for a sub total and this sub total change when im changing value for its textfields, however as this fields for TotalSavings and TotalVariable changes its supposed to change the value for my TotalExpenses as well but its not doing it. the textfields for my TotalSavings, TotalVariable and TotalExpenses are read-only, how can i make my TotalExpenses change as per value from my sub totals: TotalSavings and TotalVariable

here are my js code for sub total,

```
$(function() {
    $("#Insurance, #COL, #Saveup, #SSS").keyup(function() {
        var i = parseInt($("#Insurance").val(), 10);
        var c = parseInt($("#COL").val(), 10);
        var s = parseInt($("#Saveup").val(), 10);
        var e = parseInt($("#SSS").val(), 10);
        $("#TotalSavings").val(i + c + s + e);
    });
});


$(function() {
    $("#Fares, #Recreation, #OtherExpenses").keyup(function() {
        var f = parseFloat($("#Fares").val(), 10);
        var r = parseFloat($("#Recreation").val(), 10);
    var o = parseFloat($("#OtherExpenses").val(), 10);
        $("#TotalVariable").val(f + r + o);
    });
});
```

and here is my grand total js code,

```
$(function() {
    $("#TotalSavings, #TotalVariable").keyup(function() {
        var t1 = parseFloat($("#TotalSavings").val(), 10);
        var t2 = parseFloat($("#TotalVariable").val(), 10);
        $("#TotalExpenses").val(t1 + t2);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have 3 separate DOM ready functions, put all these `keyup` handlers into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `keyUp` handler for total value counting, use function for this. 
In your case `keyUp` callback function for `TotalSavings` and `TotalVariable` is never called because the changes are made programmatically by script, not by user input.

```
$(function() {
    $("#Insurance, #COL, #Saveup, #SSS").keyup(function() {
        var i = parseInt($("#Insurance").val(), 10);
        var c = parseInt($("#COL").val(), 10);
        var s = parseInt($("#Saveup").val(), 10);
        var e = parseInt($("#SSS").val(), 10);
        $("#TotalSavings").val(i + c + s + e);
        updateTotalExpenses();
    });

    $("#Fares, #Recreation, #OtherExpenses").keyup(function() {
        var f = parseFloat($("#Fares").val(), 10);
        var r = parseFloat($("#Recreation").val(), 10);
    var o = parseFloat($("#OtherExpenses").val(), 10);
        $("#TotalVariable").val(f + r + o);
        updateTotalExpenses();
    });
});


function updateTotalExpenses() {
    var t1 = parseFloat($("#TotalSavings").val(), 10);
    var t2 = parseFloat($("#TotalVariable").val(), 10);
    $("#TotalExpenses").val(t1 + t2);
});
```

Comment: thank you, it seemed to work...but for some reason the computation is incorrect now, earlier when i havent changed to your code im adding subtotals and its correct...now when i used ur code...TotalExpenses is giving 21 for a 11+11...

Comment: ooopppsss.....sorry...ignore my first comment...ive corrected the variables and its working perfectly now...thank you very much for the input and for ur help...